# SetConsoleDisplayMode sin definir - errores usando windows.h en C

Tags: c, windows, mingw

Estoy intentando hacer un programa para probar windows.h. He incluido la librería <windows.h> y he actualizado MinGW por si había algún problema con la versión. Os dejo a continuación el código y el output.

Código:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    COORD coords;
    SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, &coords);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Al compilar esto con "mingw32-gcc main.c" el output que obtengo es:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:107:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SetConsoleDisplayMode' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, &coords);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:107:60: error: 'CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE' undeclared (first use in this function)
     SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, &coords);
                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:107:60: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Llevo varias horas buscando a ver si encuentro alguna solución y nada de momento, espero vuestra ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: Quizás debas instalar el SDK de Windows: https://developer.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

Comment: Acabo de descargarlo. Parece ser que el problema por el que no me está encontrando dicha función es por que requiere incluir consoleapi3.h, lo he intentado incluir pero me dice que ese fichero no existe, a pesar de estar en D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\consoleapi3.h. He probado a añadir la direccion entera, pero me dice que consoleapi3.h tiene un include de apiset.h (que tambien lo tengo en D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\apiset.h). Como puedo hacer para que solo tenga que poner #include <consoleapi3.h>?